# Suma de Inputs con resultado automático

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Tengo un formulario con 3 input donde se colocan algunas cantidades enteras o decimales.

Lo que quiero es que al ir colocando cantidades en cada input se vaya sumando con el otro sin necesidad de dar clic en un botón de calcular, sino que se muestre el resultado en otro input o en un label.

Comment: Coloca el código que has usado, para poder ayudarte y ver donde te falla

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Usa el siguiente código:

```js
/* Sumar dos números. */
function sumar (valor) {
    var total = 0; 
    valor = parseInt(valor); // Convertir el valor a un entero (número).
 
    total = document.getElementById('spTotal').innerHTML;
 
    // Aquí valido si hay un valor previo, si no hay datos, le pongo un cero "0".
    total = (total == null || total == undefined || total == "") ? 0 : total;
 
    /* Esta es la suma. */
    total = (parseInt(total) + parseInt(valor));
 
    // Colocar el resultado de la suma en el control "span".
    document.getElementById('spTotal').innerHTML = total;
}
```

```html
<span>Valor #1</span>
<input type="text" id="txt_campo_1" onchange="sumar(this.value);" />
<br/ >
<span>Valor #2</span>
<input type="text" id="txt_campo_2" onchange="sumar(this.value);" />
<br/ >
<span>Valor #3</span>
<input type="text" id="txt_campo_3" onchange="sumar(this.value);" />
<br/ >
<span>El resultado es: </span> <span id="spTotal"></span>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Funciona Perfecto Mil Gracias

Comment: Con todo gusto, @Fernando y bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Para futuras preguntas que tengas, te recomiendo leer esta [guía acerca de cómo preguntar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), para así obtener reputación y añadir valor a nuestro sitio.

Comment: Como se realiza para poder pasar el valor del span  a php para poder insertarlo en la base de datos ?

Comment: @Fernando, esa es una pregunta separada, te recomiendo primero buscar cómo puedes hacer esto, si no encuentras cómo hacerlo, publica una nueva pregunta. **asegúrate de que en la nueva pregunta coloques qué has intentado hasta el momento**.
Saludos.

Comment: Ya encontré como realizarlo Gracias

Comment: Una alternativa, para que vaya sumando mientras se tipea, es utilizar el evento [oninput](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/oninput) (en vez de [onchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/onchange))

Comment: y si quiero hacer una multiplicacion como seria?

Comment: Deseo hacer una pregunta: ¿Como seria en el ultimo ejemplo, si todos los valores se exponen con 2 decimales? Desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 13):

Consiste en sumar automáticamente el valor escrito en una serie de `inputs` identificados con la clase *monto*.

Cada vez que presionas una tecla dentro del `input` se genera el evento `onkeyup`, el cual llama a una función denominada `suma`.

La función `suma` obtiene todos los elementos con la clase `monto` en forma de arreglo; este arreglo se recorre mediante un each para acceder al atributo `value` de cada `input` y si el contenido del `value` tiene un número válido, entonces se añade su valor al contador total, si el contenido del `value` no es válido, entonces se añade un cero al contador total.

Al finalizar el recorrido, el valor del contador se muestra en el elemento identificado con el id **spTotal**.

```js
function sumar() {

  var total = 0;

  $(".monto").each(function() {

    if (isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {

      total += 0;

    } else {

      total += parseFloat($(this).val());

    }

  });

  //alert(total);
  document.getElementById('spTotal').innerHTML = total;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span>Valor #1</span>
<input type="text" id="txt_campo_1" class="monto" onkeyup="sumar();" />
<br/>

<span>Valor #2</span>
<input type="text" id="txt_campo_2" class="monto" onkeyup="sumar();" />
<br/>

<span>Valor #3</span>
<input type="text" id="txt_campo_3" class="monto" onkeyup="sumar();" />
<br/>

<span>El resultado es: </span> <span id="spTotal"></span>
```

Comment: Para complementar la solución podrías poner algún texto explicativo de lo que hace

Comment: Hola, pues, basicamente este codigo da solucion a la inquietud del amigo,  consiste en  sumar automaticamente el valor escrito en una serie de inputs identificados con la clase monto.

Comment: Pipe puedes editar la solución y ponerlo a la cabecera

Answer (score 1):

Suma automáticamente todos los valores de los inputs con la clase `monto` cada vez que alguno es modificado:

```js
function sumar()
{
  const $total = document.getElementById('total');
  let subtotal = 0;
  [ ...document.getElementsByClassName( "monto" ) ].forEach( function ( element ) {
    if(element.value !== '') {
      subtotal += parseFloat(element.value);
    }
  });
  $total.value = subtotal;
}
```

```html
<span>Valor #1</span>
<input type="number" id="txt_campo_1" class="monto" onchange="sumar();" />
<br/>

<span>Valor #2</span>
<input type="number" id="txt_campo_2" class="monto" onchange="sumar();" />
<br/>

<span>Valor #3</span>
<input type="number" id="txt_campo_3" class="monto" onchange="sumar();" />

<hr>
<span>TOTAL </span>
<input type="number" id="total" value="0" readonly/>
```