# ¿Cómo lo hago para incrementar cantidad desde un input y se modifique la cantidad en un span?

Tags: javascript, html

Pues esa es mi pregunta, estoy aprendiendo javascript y en un ejercicio de clase me piden que incremente la cantidad de una celda y tenga repercusión en un span.
En mi caso tengo que aumentar el número de unidades, que deberá incrementar el precio correspondiente en la celda del total.

**Trozo de código HTML**

```
<table class="table table-condensed" id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Nombre producto</th>
                <th>Cantidad</th>
                        <th>Precio unitario</th>
                <th>Precio</th>
                <th>Acciones</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbodyusuarios">
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>Camiseta</td>
              <td><input type="number" id="cantidadCamiseta" value="3" precio="5" onclick="incrementPriceRow1"></td>
                <td><span>5</span>€</td>
              <td><span id="precioFila1">15</span>€</td>
              <td>
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" onclick="deleteRow(this)">Eliminar</button>
            </td>
```

**Mi método en javascript**

```
function incrementPriceRow1(){
    var precioFila1 = document.getElementById("precioFila1").innerHTML;

    var cantidadCamiseta = document.getElementById("cantidadCamiseta").value;

    return cantidadCamiseta*precioFila1;

}
```

Comment: Sé que hay cosas con jquery pero añado que me han encomendado esta tarea únicmanete para javascript y html

Comment: ¿Dónde se llama a la función `incrementPriceRow1`?

Comment: He puesto la llamada a la función, he reeditado el post, pero continúa sin funcionar, tengo la impresión de que no está obteniendo los valores correctamente

Comment: @Jose tienes 2 respuestas funcionales

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Suma de Inputs con resultado automatico](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/20276/suma-de-inputs-con-resultado-automatico)

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por las respuestas aunque solo pueda marcar una sé que las demás también son funcionales, un saludo a todos!

Comment: @Mauricio creo que esta pregunta esta mejor redactada y ha tenido mas atención que la pregunta con la que quieren ponerla duplicada, creo que esta deberia ser la principal y la otra la duplicada

Comment: @jasilva tienes razón. Lo consideraré, creo que me equivoqué al reportar la pregunta "me fije además, por la fecha de creación de la pregunta" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifique tu funcion `incrementPriceRow1()`, ademas que esta funcion no estaba siendo usada, y para solucionar el problema no necesitas devolver nada.

> con la funcion `value` obtengo los caracteres del campo
>
> con la funcion `innerHTML` inserto texto

cree un `id="precio"` en el span de precio, para obtener el texto del span y luego con parseInt() convertirlo a numero

solucionando tu problema:

```js
function incrementPriceRow1(){
  
    var precioFila1 = document.getElementById("precioFila1");
    var precio = document.getElementById("precio").innerHTML;
    
    var cantidadCamiseta =document.getElementById("cantidadCamiseta").value;
    var total=parseInt(cantidadCamiseta)*parseInt(precio);
    precioFila1.innerHTML=total;


}
```

```html
<table class="table table-condensed" id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Nombre producto</th>
                <th>Cantidad</th>
                        <th>Precio unitario</th>
                <th>Precio</th>
                <th>Acciones</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbodyusuarios">
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>Camiseta</td>
              <td><input type="number" id="cantidadCamiseta" value="" precio="5"></td>
                <td><span id="precio">5</span>€</td>
              <td><span id="precioFila1"></span>€</td>
              <td>
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" onclick="incrementPriceRow1()">prueba</button>
            </td>
```

Comment: Correcto!! funciona!! muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3):

Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

- En lugar de usar `ids`, podrías usar `class` para identificar los distintos datos en la fila.

  - `class="cantidad"` para identificar los `input`
  - `class="precio"` para identificar los `span` con el `precio`
  - `class="total"` para identificar los `span` donde se guarda el `total`.
- Te suscribes al evento `input`, el cual se dispara cada vez que se cambia el valor de los `input.cantidad`, buscas dentro de la fila el `precio` y estableces el `total`, multiplicando `cantidad * precio`.

Así por ejemplo:

```js
$('#tbodyusuarios')
  .on('input', '.cantidad', function() {
    var $input = $(this), // input.cantidad
        cantidad = parseInt($input.val(), 10), // valor de input.cantidad
        $tr = $input.closest('tr'), // fila del input.canitdad
        precio = parseInt($tr.find('.precio').text(), 10), // valor del span.precio
        $total = $tr.find('.total'); // elemento span.total
    
    $total.text(precio * cantidad); // seteamo el valor del span.total
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-condensed" id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Nombre producto</th>
      <th>Cantidad</th>
      <th>Precio unitario</th>
      <th>Precio</th>
      <th>Acciones</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbodyusuarios">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Camiseta</td>
      <td><input type="number" class="cantidad" value="3"/></td>
      <td><span class="precio">5</span>€</td>
      <td><span class="total">15</span>€</td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" onclick="deleteRow(this)">Eliminar</button></td>
     </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Pantalon</td>
      <td><input type="number" class="cantidad" value="1"/></td>
      <td><span class="precio">8</span>€</td>
      <td><span class="total">8</span>€</td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" onclick="deleteRow(this)">Eliminar</button></td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

El código que compartes presenta varios problemas:

- A la llamada a la función `incrementPriceRow1` le faltan los paréntesis, debería ser así: `incrementPriceRow1()`.
- Estás multiplicando los valores incorrectos: no quieres multiplicar la cantidad y el PrecioFila1, lo que quieres multiplicar es la cantidad por la cantidad/precio unitario. Para ello:

  - añade un ID al `span` que contiene el precio unitario
  - Usa el nuevo id en lugar de PrecioFila1
- No hace falta que la función devuelva nada, lo que debe hacer es cambiar el valor de PrecioFila1, que se puede hacer asignándole el valor al `innerHTML`.

Corriendo eso, te queda algo así que ya funciona sin problemas:

```js
function incrementPriceRow1(){
  
    var precioUnitario = document.getElementById("precioUnitario").innerHTML;
    var cantidadCamiseta = document.getElementById("cantidadCamiseta").value;

    document.getElementById("precioFila1").innerHTML = cantidadCamiseta * precioUnitario;

}
```

```html
<table class="table table-condensed" id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Nombre producto</th>
      <th>Cantidad</th>
      <th>Precio unitario</th>
      <th>Precio</th>
      <th>Acciones</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tbodyusuarios">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Camiseta</td>
      <td><input type="number" id="cantidadCamiseta" value="3" precio="5" onclick="incrementPriceRow1()"></td>
      <td><span id="precioUnitario">5</span>€</td>
      <td><span id="precioFila1">15</span>€</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" onclick="deleteRow(this)">Eliminar</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```