# hacer funcion Javascript al suceder varios eventos

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buen dia!

tengo 5 inputs los cuales quiero que en un label aparezca la suma de los 5 pero dinamicamente, es decir a medida que voy digitanto los numeros en los inputs, ejemplo si en el iunput 1 digité el 3 y en el input 2 digité el 4 me muestre en seguida el resultado en el label o sea 6 y asi sucesivamente...

pienso usar un script de autocompletar un input que lo tengo funcionando el cual detecta cuando una tecla se oprime y realiza una funcion para el caso completar un input de acuerdo a una base de datos que eso no viene al tema

este es el script

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('#input_1').typeahead(
  {
    //aquí haré la suma e imprimiré en el label

  });
});
```

como pueden ver solo me serviría para el input_1

como puedo agregarle mas input? separandolos por coma despues del input_1
?

Comment: ¿No te serviría mejor trabajar los input en modo arreglo? O ya que usas JQuery, ¿llamarlos por una clase que todos compartan? Así te evitas tener que ir 1 a 1, y sólo los recorres como una colección (si es que el lenguaje no tiene implementado ya una forma de bucle en una sola línea).

Comment: Checa esta [publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/20276/suma-de-inputs-con-resultado-automático) muy similar a la que tu deseas realizar.

Comment: 3 + 4 = 6 Tenia que decirlo

Comment: jajajaja también me percaté de su error en la suma  xD, de igual modo si se da a entender a lo que necesita.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //guardara el total
  var total = 0;

  //cuando haya un cambio en el input
  //Si no quisieras tomar todos los input bastara con asignarles una clase 
  //Si asignas una clase bastara con $('input') por $('.tuclase')
  $('input').change(function() {

    //valida que sea un numero
    if (!isNaN($(this).val())) {

      //va acumulando el total
      total += Number($(this).val());

      //muestra el total
      $("#resultado").text(total);

    } else {
      //Si no introduce numero genera alerta
      alert("Debe ingresar un numero");
    }

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text"><br>
<p>Total: <span id="resultado"> 0</span></p>
```

**EDIT**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //cada vez que el usuario orpime una tacla
  $('input').keyup(function() {
    var total = 0;

    //recorremos los input para que haga la suma
    $("input").each(
      function(index, value) {
        if ($.isNumeric($(this).val())) {
          total = total + eval($(this).val());
        }
      });
    $("#resultado").text(total);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text"><br>
<p>Total: <span id="resultado"> 0</span></p>
```

Comment: Excelente Luis!! funciona de maravilla... disculpa ser tan exigente pero existe una forma que apenas oprima la tecla haga la suma, lo digo por que si la hace pero debo dar click en otro input o en algun lugar de la pagina para que la haga... esto causaria que por ejemplo un usuario vea la suma de los 5 inputs cuando este llenando el quinto pero en realidad estaria sumando 4 ya que debe salirse del input con el clic del mouse... gracias!!

Comment: Pregunta actualizada, si te fue util puedes marcar la respuesta como acepatada. +1

Answer (score 2):

haz la referencia por clases en vez de por `#id`

por ejemplo

```
<input type="text" class="example">
<input type="text" class="example">
<input type="text" class="example">
```

y luego

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('.example').typeahead(
  {
    //aquí haré la suma e imprimiré en el label

  });
});
```

de esta forma bindeas el evento a cada input con la clase example

Answer (score 2):

Puedes utilizar un patrón para seleccionar todos los inputs por sus ids. Todos los inputs que su id empiece por **input_**.

**HTML**

```
<input id="input_1" type="text">
<input id="input_2" type="text">
<input id="input_3" type="text">
<input id="input_4" type="text">
<input id="input_5" type="text">
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("input[id^='input_']").typeahead(
  {
    //aquí haré la suma e imprimiré en el label

  });
});
```