# input escrito y otro automático

Tags: javascript

Capturo los dos valores que dígito y quiero sumar esos dos valores a otro input
pero quiero que sea automática la escritura en el 3 input.
escribo 5  y 7 y en el tercer input que se esciba automatico 12. Gracias.

```
window.addEventListener('load',iniciar,false);
function iniciar(){
    cantidad_viajes = document.getElementById("cantidad_viajes").value;
    valor_unitario = document.getElementById("valor_unitario").value;
}
```

Comment: Tal vez esto te puede ayudar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/20276/suma-de-inputs-con-resultado-autom%C3%A1tico

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te faltò unicamente pasar la suma al tercer input. lo puedes hacer con el evento `keyup`

```js
function sumar() {
 let input1 = Number( document.getElementById('input1').value );
 let input2 = Number( document.getElementById('input2').value );
 let sum = input1 + input2;
 
 document.getElementById('input3').value = sum;

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input1" onkeyup="sumar()">
<input type="text" id="input2" onkeyup="sumar()">
<input type="text" id="input3" readonly>
```

Comment: Me funciono bien a mi, pero digamos y si quiero sumar los resultados que se estan imprimiendo en el input3 con otra cantidad o incluso otro resultado como por ejemplo input3 + input4