# ¿Como sumar columnas intercaladas para imprimir el resultado en una columna y no en pie de pagina?

Tags: php, ajax, phpmyadmin, datatables

Esta es la tabla que deseo modificar, tiene el "semestre" (Se agrega texto) y "total" (Ahi se agrega la cantidad de creditos que hizo) y en la columna 3 con nombre "Total de creditos" deseo sumar 12 veces esos totales e imprimirlos ahi, pero hacer que reconozca el id de los alumnos y lo sume dependiendo de sus creditos acomulados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<div class="container caja">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="tablaUsuarios" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed" style="width:100%">
          <thead class="text-center">
            <tr>
              <th>Id</th>
              <th>Numero de Control</th>
              <th>Nombre del Alumno</th>
              <th>total de Creditos</th>
              <th>Semestre 1</th>
              <th>total</th>
              <th>Semestre 2</th>
              <th>total</th>
              <th>Semestre 3</th>
              <th>total</th>
              <th>Semestre 4</th>
              <th>total</th>
              <th>Semestre 5</th>
              <th>total</th>
              <th>Semestre 6</th>
              <th>total</th>
              <th>Semestre 7</th>
              <th>total</th>
              <th>Semestre 8</th>
              <th>total</th>
              <th>Semestre 9</th>
              <th>total</th>
              <th>Semestre 10</th>
              <th>total</th>
              <th>Semestre 11</th>
              <th>total</th>
              <th>Semestre 12</th>
              <th>total</th>
              <th>Status</th>
              <th>Acciones</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

*ESTOY USANDO UN CRUD CON PHP Y AJAX,ESTE CRUD PARA EDITAR LOS DATOS YA FUNCIONA PERO NECESITO QUE RECONOZCA LOS NUMEROS Y LOS SUME*

<

**Esto es lo que intente, cambie el id y asigne el numero correspondiente a la columna de los "totales" y lo dirigi al id de creditos totales que es "totalcreditos" para ahi hacer la suma**
->Cambie el id de la tabla y agrege las librerias correspondientes

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tablaUsarios').dataTable({
        "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
            var api = this.api(), data;
 
            // converting to interger to find total
            var intVal = function ( i ) {
                return typeof i === 'string' ?
                    i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                    typeof i === 'number' ?
                        i : 0;
            };
 
            // computing column total of the complete result 
            var total1 = api
                .column( 5 )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );
                
        var total2 = api
                .column( 7 )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );
                
            var total3 = api
                .column( 9 )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );
                
         var total4 = api
                .column( 11 )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );
                
         var total5 = api
                .column( 13 )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );
        var total6 = api
                .column( 15 )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );
        var total7 = api
                .column( 17 )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );
        var total8 = api
                .column( 19 )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );
        var total9 = api
                .column( 21 )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );
            
        var total10 = api
                .column( 23 )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );
                               
        var total11 = api
                .column( 25 )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );
         var total12 = api
                .column( 27 )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );
                
                
            // Update footer by showing the total with the reference of the column index 
        $( api.column( 3 ).footer() ).html('totalcreditos');
            $( api.column( 5 ).footer() ).html(total1);
            $( api.column( 7 ).footer() ).html(total2);
            $( api.column( 9 ).footer() ).html(total3);
            $( api.column( 11 ).footer() ).html(total4);
            $( api.column( 13 ).footer() ).html(total5);
            $( api.column( 15 ).footer() ).html(total6);
            $( api.column( 17 ).footer() ).html(total7);
            $( api.column( 19 ).footer() ).html(total8);
            $( api.column( 21 ).footer() ).html(total9);
            $( api.column( 23 ).footer() ).html(total10);
            $( api.column( 25 ).footer() ).html(total11);
            $( api.column( 27 ).footer() ).html(total12);
        },
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "server.php"
    } );
} );
</script>
```

Comment: y que has intentado para que sume??? de paso te recomiendo hacer el [tour]

Comment: Intente usar este script pero hacerlo para que quede en esa columna < https://phppot.com/jquery/calculate-sum-total-of-datatables-column-using-footer-callback/ > (Hare el recorrido de bienvendida)

Comment: ok edita tu publicacion y agrega lo que intentaste... tal vez hay podriamos encontra el error ...

Comment: Ya edite, gracias

Comment: En tu tabla debes agregar un par de datos de ejemplo (no solo la cabecera), además no me queda claro lo que quieres decir con `deseo sumar 12 veces esos totales e imprimirlos ahi`

Comment: Mil disculpas por no saberme entender. Esto resolvio mi problema, al parecer es algo simple pero util < https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/20276/suma-de-inputs-con-resultado-autom%C3%A1tico >